# mod_rewrite allow all characters and numbers and latters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

`([0-9a-zA-Z/+]+)` 
currently, I'm using this rule also I want `+` and `%` to be allowed in this rule how to do it? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule is already allowing `+`, you just need to add `%` into your regexp. It should be like that: `([0-9a-zA-Z/+%]+)`